# Integrating Html5Boilerplate's Builder into a WP Theme

Tags: theme-development, html5

So Im planning to use [Html5Boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/) as a base to build a new WP Theme on.
The Boilerplate comes with the Builder, a handy Tool for minifiying, concatenating and compressing ones Website for obvious reasons: speed/performance-gain, easier mobile access and so on.

I would very much like to use this feature with my theme. Problem: The builder outputs the processed files into a subdir /publish. Without WP one could use a .htaccess rule to reroute the base domain, e.g. mysite.net to mysite.net/publish. This is the method proposed by Html5Boilerplate.

Since I can't possibly use this approach in a Theme, I would need a way to tell WP to go looking for the Theme's files in the /publish subdir of the actual Theme dir. Anyone know a way to do that?

Alternatively, is there a way to tell The build script to look for the source Files in a subdir, and to subsequently publish the files into the theme root?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several starter themes out there based on HTML5 Boilerplate, so you may find that forking one of them is a better option that rolling your own.

- [Eulerplate](https://github.com/bytefair/eulerplate)
- [Essence](https://github.com/kevva/essence)
- [Roots](http://www.rootstheme.com/)
- [Bones](https://github.com/eddiemachado/bones)
- [Boilerplate](http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/boilerplate)
- [HTML5 Boilerplate for WordPress](https://github.com/zencoder/html5-boilerplate-for-wordpress)

Answer (score 3):

Looks like someone has the documentation to assist with this:

https://github.com/h5bp/ant-build-script/wiki/Configuration-Cookbook

Comment: Thanks for anwering, thats a usefukl link! This is another issue that arises with WP and h5bp, but changing the style / js reference paths that the builder outputs is not my original problem. I need builder to deploy to my theme root directory, instead of the /publish subdirectory.

Comment: I was looking over the config/project.properties. On line 104 there look like the place where you would override the setting for the publish directory